# Python muliprocessing - Get values from manager.list()

Tags: python, shared-memory, python-multiprocessing

I have the following code:

```
from multiprocessing import Manager

manager = Manager()
shared_list= manager.list()
#fill shared_list using some processes
```

and then I'd like to put the results from the shared_arr to a list.

```
print shared_list[0:ind]
```

outputs the content of the shared list, however, I can't do

```
buffer = Array(c_char_p, len(data))
buffer[0:ind] = shared_list[0:ind]
```

since `buffer` is then filled with junk like `LINGER` and `softspace`. How can I get the data out of the `shared_list` into another variable? Thank you!